# How to add library ending with numbers (libXXX.so.1) in Unity3D assets

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm creating a Unity3D application which depends of libraries named as libXXX.so.1

Unity are not bundle them into the assets: I can't select them in the editor and they are just ignored if I put them into the Assets folder.

It's working well if library names are libXXX.so, but renaming breaks the links between libraries.

How to force Unity to include those libraries inside Plugins folders?

I want to create a distribuable unitypackage so I can't just copy them to the output folder after each build.

Source folder:

```
    find . -name "*.so*"
    ./Assets/Plugins/Linux/libTest1.so
    ./Assets/Plugins/Linux/libTest2.so.1
```

Build foder:

```
    find . -name "*.so*"
    ./Project_Data/Mono/x86_64/libmono.so
    ./Project_Data/Mono/x86_64/libMonoPosixHelper.so
    ./Project_Data/Plugins/libTest1.so
    ./Project_Data/Plugins/x86_64/ScreenSelector.so
    ./LinuxPlayer.so
```

Answer (score 0):

Unity3D will include all the files that are in the Assets/Resources folder (and all sub-folders under Assets/Resources).  Check out this document page:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html